# Is it a good idea to cache a sitemap.xml?

Tags: symfony, varnish, varnish-4, sitemap.xml

I have a sitemap.xml page which is dynamically generated by my Symfony application. I also use Varnish. I would like to know if it's a good idea to cache the sitemap.xml page or if it's useless?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't cache anything just because you can. Is there any scientific proof that you need it? If there is no - you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @zerkms.

Comment: Completely disagree with @zerkms - cache everything you can. Don't forget to invalidate the cache when needed (when content is updated).

Comment: Thanks for sharing your point of view @seven. I, actually, cached it.

Answer (score 1):

How often will it change? If it isn't changing on a minute-by-minute basis, but is being read often (and hence being generated often), then it's probably worth caching it. You may want some code to generate it offline and then invalidate the Varnish cache if a particular timeliness for a newly update file is required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alister. It's a CMS so it can often change. Like at least once in a day. My question was more about if the sitemap must be cached. We set the 'changefreq' to 1 day and only search engines request this page. Therefore, the traffic to this page is very low. But, even if it was changing every minute, I don't think we can have a lot of calls to this page. Maybe I'm wrong. But that's why I asked if it's useful to cache it.

Comment: "But, even if it was changing every minute, I don't think we can have a lot of calls to this page." --- so what problem you're solving with caching it?